# Problems with OpenRTI callbacks

Tags: hla

How in the OpenRTI to make the rti send callbacks? For example, reserve a name with the `reserveObjectInstanceName`

```
_rtiAmbassador->reserveObjectInstanceName(name);
```

Errors:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'rti1516e::ObjectInstanceNameNotReserved'

Comment: Please read the [info of the hla tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hla/info) and decide if this tag matches [your HLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Architecture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the HLA 1516e API (as opposed to HLA 1516 or HLA 1.3) when you make a call to `connect` you can specify a `CallbackModel` which is either `SYNCHRONOUS` or `ASYNCHRONOUS`. In a synchronous callback model, the federate has to call the method `evokeCallback` in order to trigger the RTI to send whatever is queued up. In asynchronous, the callbacks are sent automatically.

What you should do in this instance is have something like this:

```
_rtiAmbassador->reserveObjectInstanceName(std::wstring(L"MyObject"));
_rtiAmbassador->evokeMultipleCallbacks();
MyFederateAmbassador::objectInstanceNameReservationSucceeded(std::wstring const & name){
    _rtiAmbassador->registerObjectInstance(handle, std::wstring(L"MyObject"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each call to RTI, to get a callback, you need to call 
evokeCallback()